# Estimating higher order moments in OLS in R

Tags: r, loops, statistics, mapply

I'm trying to get some fancy OLS estimator manullay in R.

My code is

```
library(moments)
x=list()
epsilon=list()
y=list()
eta=list()



for (i in 1:1000) {
  x[[i]]=rnorm(100, mean=1, sd=1)
  epsilon[[i]]=rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=1)
}
i=c(1,2,4,8)
for (k in i) {
  eta[[k]]=lapply(epsilon[[k]], moment, order=k, central=T)
}
eta=eta %>% keep( ~ !is.null(.) )

for (k in i) {
  y[[k]]=mapply(function(x, eta) x[[k]]+eta[[k]], x, eta)
  
}
y=y %>% keep( ~ !is.null(.) )

}
estimator=list()
for (k in i) {
  estimator[[k]]=mapply(function(x,y) inv(t(x[[k]])%*%x[[k]])%*%(t(x[[k]])%*%y[[k]]), x, y )
}
```

I'm interested in looking at the effect of calculating higher order moments in epsilon, and hence, doing this exercise recursively. That's why the function "moment".

Before that, though, I need to get y in the correct dimension. My code has several issues:1) when I do "t(x[[1]]%*%x[[1]]" (as an example) I get a scalar, instead of a 100x100 matrix. 2) y should be a list with 4 elements, each of length 100 (so that dimensions match when doing the OLS estimator).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You never make x[[i]] into a matrix. Furthermore, if it were supposed to be a 100x 100 matrix, shouldn’t it have been `rnorm(10000,,)`? A vector %x% vector is a scalar.

Comment: if every x[[i]] is a 100x1, then, t(x[[i]])*x[[i]] should be a matrix 100x100 matrix by defintion, right?

Comment: I would use outer product code `x[[1]] %o% x[[1]]` to get a 100x100. No `t()` transform needed.

Comment: Thanks! this works! any ideas for the dimension of y?

Comment: already did. The questions are the two issues. 1) is solved by using  %o%
Now I'm only missing the issue with the dimension of y